# HTTR warning when there is no data in desired response

Tags: r, tidyverse, httr

I am building an API wrapper using `httr`.  The API I'm using doesn't have content within `people` for the current year, but returns data for the copyright.  When I use `httr::GET` I still get a 200 status code since there is a response.

The response should have data similar to 2019.  How do I use `httr` to throw an error?  Is there a warning similar to `httr::warn_for_status` available?

Example of request that works and returns people, vs. one that doesn't

```r
library(httr)

data <- GET("https://statsapi.mlb.com/api/v1/sports/1/players?season=2019")
# response with data in content.  I'll spare everyone the 1,410 rows in the JSON Response
str(content(data, type= "application/json"), list.len = 2)
#> List of 2
#>  $ copyright: chr "Copyright 2020 MLB Advanced Media, L.P.  Use of any content on this page acknowledges agreement to the terms po"| __truncated__
#>  $ people   :List of 1410
#>   ..$ :List of 36
#>   .. ..$ id              : int 472551
#>   .. ..$ fullName        : chr "Fernando Abad"
#>   .. .. [list output truncated]
#>   ..$ :List of 35
#>   .. ..$ id              : int 650556
#>   .. ..$ fullName        : chr "Bryan Abreu"
#>   .. .. [list output truncated]
#>   .. [list output truncated]

no_data <- GET("https://statsapi.mlb.com/api/v1/sports/1/players?season=2020")

str(content(no_data, type= "application/json"))
#> List of 2
#>  $ copyright: chr "Copyright 2020 MLB Advanced Media, L.P.  Use of any content on this page acknowledges agreement to the terms po"| __truncated__
#>  $ people   : list()
```

The alternative I've used is to parse the data and then use `nrow(df) < 1`.  There has to be a better way.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with checking the length of the result. The API clearly "worked" but it just returned no data. Getting no results for a search isn't really an error. I'm really not sure what types of alternatives you were looking for. This all seems very reasonable to me.

Comment: I'm with @MrFlick here. Maybe you are trying to make a function around `httr` and get an error message when `length(people) == 0`? If that's the case, what would be the issue?

Comment: No issues, I was just wondering if there was a better way to do this then my current way. @David Jorquera Any suggestions for a function to do what you are referring to?

Comment: see `?stop` to stop the execution with an error message. The stop's trigger can be what you want. There is nothing wrong with evaluating that condition checking out `people`'s length.